# add_filter function getting executed before the loading of header file in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, add-filter

[image]I have created a login page integrated with fb login.When the user clicks on forget passwords,it will redirect to a page asking to enter your username. When clicking on the submit button an error message is generated saying yu are logged in with fb and pls change the fb password.

To achieve this i have used add_filter "allow_password_reset hook". But whtever is written its getting executed before loading the header file and the output is displayed on top of header file. I have tried everything i know and still the problem exists. Here is my code:

```
function se_deny_password_reset() {
    $allow = false;
    showMessage("Error", true);
    return $allow;
}
add_filter( 'allow_password_reset', 'se_deny_password_reset', 10, 2 );


function showMessage($message, $errormsg = false)
{
  echo '<p><strong>' . $message . '</strong></p></div>';
}
```

Comment: Yes, that filter is run very early in the WP run.  You should not be echoing anything at that point.  Just return FALSE.  If you need to echo a message for some reason, then you should TRACK the state of `$allow`, and then in *a different hook* you can echo your message.

Comment: Thank yu fr the cmnt, But am confused ! how can v track the status of a variable($allow).

Answer (score 0):

NOTE:

Your question does not make clear WHERE you want the message shown, so this is just a pattern you could use to track the status of your `$allow` variable, so that you can in turn display the message as you see fit:

(Use this code instead of the functions you already have in place)

```
class MyPasswordClass {

    /**
     * Track the state of $allow.
     * Change if desired in a class function like so: $this->allow = TRUE;
     *
     * @var bool
     */
    private $allow = FALSE;

    /**
     * Constructor.
     * Set up the action / filter hooks.
     */
    public function __construct() {
        add_filter( 'allow_password_reset', array( $this, 'allow_password_reset' ), 10, 2 );
        add_filter( 'retrieve_password_message', array( $this, 'password_message' ), 10, 4 );
    }

    /**
     * Hooks into WP 'allow_password_reset' filter.
     *
     * @param bool $allow
     * @param int  $user_id
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function allow_password_reset( $allow, $user_id ) {
        // If desired, change permission.  Example:
        // $this->allow = TRUE;

        return $this->allow;
    }

    /**
     * Hooks into WP 'retrieve_password_message' filter.
     * Message that displays when user attempts to reset password.
     *
     * @param string $message
     * @param string $key
     * @param string $user_login
     * @param object $user_data
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function password_message( $message, $key, $user_login, $user_data ) {
        $message = 'My custom error message.';
        return $message;
    }
}

// Instantiate the class so that the filters are set up / used
new MyPasswordClass();
```